lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.4-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException Exception on Gradle build in Flutter
Im trying to run my flutter project as 2 days ago but today i've had this exception from the terminal:
ERROR:C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\8.10\transforms\de8b7c279bab57b19bedbdae5123190e\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.4-runtime.jar: D8: java.lang.NullPointerException
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.


Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.4.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.8.4) to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, asm-transformed-variant=NONE, dexing-enable-desugaring=true, dexing-enable-jacoco-instrumentation=false, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=21, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> Execution failed for DexingWithClasspathTransform: C:\Users\rikyt.gradle\caches\8.10\transforms\de8b7c279bab57b19bedbdae5123190e\transformed\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.8.4-runtime.jar.
> Error while dexing.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              5,6s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
To fix the problem i've already updated all the dependencies, pub, java, gradle and flutter versions... but nothing. I hope that someone knows the solution.
